# GLSL Lighting with attenuation; how to add a fade-out color?

Tags: glsl

I am using the GLSL shader from this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/glsl-light-attenuation-color-and-intensity-formula), slightly modified and i got it working.
The shader code is the following:

**VS:**

```
  vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);        
  vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;              
  gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
```

**FS:**

```
  float minLight = 0.01f;      
  float radius = sqrt(1.0 / (uAttenuationFactor * minLight));   
  float lightAdd = 0.0f;       
  float dist = distance(vPosition.xyz, (uMat4Identity * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz);  
  float att = clamp(1.0 - dist/radius, 0.0, 1.0);    
  vec3 surf2light = normalize((uMat4Identity * vec4(uLightPosition, 1.0)).xyz - vPosition.xyz);   
  vec3 norm = normalize(vTransformedNormal);     
  float diffuseCoefficient = max(0.0, dot(norm, surf2light));   
  lightAdd += att * (diffuseCoefficient + uSourceIntensity);    
  vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTex0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));  
  vec3 torch_output = lightAdd * uColorLight;     
  vec4 final_color = (vec4(torch_output, 1.0f) * textureColor) * vVertexColor;   
  gl_FragColor = final_color;
```

The shader computes point lighting with attenuation and give very satisfactory results. Look at the pic:

[image: point lighting]

I give **uAttenuationFactor = 0.4f** and **uSourceIntensity = 0.2f** to get this result and it satisfies me. However, besides setting the light color, how i could modify the shader to fade-out to another color than black?? Anything i tried it just modifies the visible parts of the screen i.e. walls but the black remains unchanged. I would had liked to be able to set a grey color for rain or whitish for fog effect etc.

Thanx.

Comment: You could try applying a simple "fog" method. You could achieve that by simply using the depth buffer and coloring based on each depth value..

Comment: @Sidar, thanx, i did not thought of that. Since i am using transparent sprites i had to disable depth writing and render back-to-front for transparent objects except for opaque objects such the walls so its kind of a half solution, unless i can fix it via shader.

Comment: That is the normal way of handling transparent objects. Do opaque objects first, disable depth write then render from back to front. Otherwise see if you can discard the fragment based on alpha instead.

Comment: Btw you could fake sprite fog by just taking the "real" distance from the cam and apply some sort of post processing. But I can't infringe on your setup =P

Comment: @Sidar, yes i am doing exactly that =) I have no problem with sprites and 3d opaque objects, all working sweet. I know i could use some fog formula and perhaps this is the right thing, fog using lighting techniques are perhaps wrong thinking =) About real distance from the cam and such seems an alternative way but i still need to mix depth buffer for opaque objects and distances for transaprent, sounds hard =) Perhaps using some dedicated fog shader might prove easier =)

Comment: I once made a fake fade effect by simply having quads move with the camera at a distance. The quad texture was a gradient from opaque to transparent ( bottom to top ). The quad was at a slight angle to create fake depth, duplicate the quad and place it a bit further from the original but a bit higher. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/Vi80GZK.png)

Comment: [Made the concept in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrzuXwDElqE&feature=youtu.be) The gradient is a bit sloppy ( just grabbed the first one i found on google) I think if you're creative with the textures and perhaps add some post processing you could get a cool effect.

Comment: @Sidar, very neat :) Unfortunately, i hate Unity with a passion :) I am using my own engine for this project and i finally solved the issue using the shader only. Check my answer

Comment: The technique isn't exclusive to unity, I just set it up to demonstrate it. You might want to accept your own answer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a number of hours, i finally found some shader way to mix both lighting and fog:

**VS:**

```
...
// fog                                 
uniform LOWP float uFogDistance;       
varying float vFogClampedDistance;    
void main() {
   ...
   // fog                          
   if (uFogDistance >= 0.0) {                                        
      vFogClampedDistance = clamp(gl_Position.z, 0.0, uFogDistance); 
   }                                                              
}
```

**FS:**

```
...
// fog                                 
uniform LOWP float uFogDistance;       
varying float vFogClampedDistance;    
void main() {
   ...
   // compute final_color by 'lighting'
   ...
   Vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTex0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));                
   if (uFogDistance == 0.0) {                                                                   
      gl_FragColor = ...use only lighting, not fog
   }                               
   else {                          
      gl_FragColor = mix(final_color, vec4(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0), vFogClampedDistance/uFogDistance) * vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,textureColor.a);   
   }
```

}

I am now able to both use the lighting shader wth attenuation, plus with a very simple fog effect which works on the lighting colors. Of course where both are mixing i have to be careful not to wash the graphics out:  Take a look in pics:

[image]
[image]

Even if i disable the lighting and use only *black* fog to simulate the lighting, the results resembles somehow those of lighting; while not perfect, they are blending nicely:

[image]

Comment: Pretty neat and simple solution. Btw you can get rid of the if statement simply by applying one of these : http://theorangeduck.com/page/avoiding-shader-conditionals. Not sure how more optimized it would be but you're fine eitherway

Comment: Thanx! Yes i know, i am using an uber shader which handles texturing, 2 types of lighting and now fog and i will certainly look for ways to avoid conditions, i will read the link, thanx =) I already optimized the fragment shader by removing the `radius` and the killer square root computation and instead moved it into a nice uniform. Frame rate is still 60ish even on my poor celeron laptop =) Having 2d sprites with autorotation helps a lot ;)

Comment: I want to clarify that I don't know how much actually gets optimized ( or not at all) but it's good to know those solutions exist. Btw you could check distance just by using the squares of your values. Unless you need the actual length then square root is probably what you need.